# Fragment becomes unresponsive when app is resumed from BackStack or called from Notification

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

In Dashboard Activity there is a Fragment on top which contains 3 fragments as view pagers inside it.The view pagers become blank and unresponsive (as shown in 2nd screenshot) in these cases:

1. When app is loaded from backstack
2. When font setting is changed while app is in background and called again from app stack
3. When the notification of my app is clicked and the click action redirects to the Dashboard Activity
   [image: Screenshot:when activity is created]

[image: Screenshot when its notification is clicked and then redirected to this activity]

The code for Fragment for tabs is:

```
public class MainActivityGraphViewPager extends Fragment {


public MainActivityGraphViewPager() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity_graph_pager, container, false);
    ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.fgraph_pager);

    TabLayout tabx = v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_dashboard);
    tabx.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapterFeaturedgraphs(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    return v;
}


private class SectionPagerAdapterFeaturedgraphs extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionPagerAdapterFeaturedgraphs(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ExpenseManagerPieChart();

            case 1:
                return new BudgetandFitness();

            case 2:
                return new ExpendsFragments();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}}
```

The MainActivityGraphViewPager.class is called in Dashboard Activity's onCreate():

```
        MainActivityGraphViewPager mainActivityGraphPager=new MainActivityGraphViewPager();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.graph_pagers, mainActivityGraphPager).commit();
```

What can be the possible solutions to remove this unresponsiveness?